# How to search string for a set of characters emacs-lisp

Tags: search, emacs

So I've been trying to do this for a while. Searching on how to do this didn't give me answers related to emacs lisp. Essentially I want to be able to search a string for a set of characters, and if the search succeeded do something else.

For example:

---

Say the string I want to search is

> "https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F4.bp.blogspot.com%2F-pGUXC8ugtWk%2FUSqy_ppFbCI%2FAAAAAAAAD6Y%2FyRSgg40BXlw%2Fs1600%2Fcat%2Bpictures.jpg&f=1"

And I want to search for the characters ".jpg", if it fails then I want to look for ".png" (essentially common image file formats). If it succeeds then I want to set the file format (e.g ".jpg") as a new variable. Does anyone have any idea on how to go about this?

I'm new to elisp, and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun my-extract-file-format (s)
  (cond
   ((string-match-p "\\.jpg" s) ".jpg")
   ((string-match-p "\\.png" s) ".png")))

(my-extract-file-format "https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F4.bp.blogspot.com%2F-pGUXC8ugtWk%2FUSqy_ppFbCI%2FAAAAAAAAD6Y%2FyRSgg40BXlw%2Fs1600%2Fcat%2Bpictures.jpg&f=1")
```

If you have too many file formats to just list them there it can be made more general of course.